# PHP dynamic title

Tags: php, dynamic, web, title

I want users to be able to dynamicly change the title of the websites.

I've tried ALL of the Dynamic Website Title questions on Stackoverflow, but none resolves my issues.

**This is my HTML**

```
<fieldset>
    <legend style='width:500px;'><h3>Website Title</h3></legend>
    <label><h4> Change Website Title </h4></label>
    <form action='Config.php' method='POST'>
    <input type='text' name='websitetitle' placeholder='Website Title'/> <br />
    <input type='submit' value='Update' class='btn btn-small btn-primary' name='update'>
    </form>
  </fieldset>
```

**Config.php**

```
   <?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['update'])) {
$title=strip_tags(stripslashes($_REQUEST['websitetitle']));
}
```

**Global.php (Where the title is located)**

```
 <title><?php include 'Config.php'; echo $title; ?> </title>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you need to save the title for later use?

Comment: You haven't stated what your problem is.  You just posted code.

Comment: Where is the code for the title output?

Comment: Where does it fail?  Is the value successfully extracted from `$_REQUEST['websitetitle']`?  Is it successfully posted to the server at all?

Comment: Put the title into `$_SESSION`.

Comment: I want users to be able to change the website title via the form

Comment: Well then your job is done, isn't it? But as someone asked before, do you need to save the changes for later? The way it works now they would have to submit the form everytime they request the page.

Comment: Yes, I want to save the changes

Comment: @Well consider the following: 1/keep the title in the URL and check for it at every page reload 2/use $_SESSION, 3/save it in a file maping say IP addresses to titles or 4/last use a database.

Comment: Can I have some examples in which sessions is being used?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have your variable `websitetitle` in  `$_REQUEST` wrong ???  As I don't "believe" you can pass the value of a "submit".

```
<fieldset>
<legend style='width:500px;'><h3>Website Title</h3></legend>
<label><h4> Change Website Title </h4></label>
<form action='Config.php' method='POST'>
<input type='text' name='websitetitle' placeholder='Website Title'/> <br />
<input type='submit' value='Update' class='btn btn-small btn-primary' name='update'>
</form>
</fieldset>
```

Then

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['websitetitle'])) {
$title=strip_tags(stripslashes($_REQUEST['websitetitle']));
}
```

Then

```
<title><?php include 'Config.php'; echo $title; ?> </title>
```

Comment: In his case when he hits submit (named update) then there will be a variable named `$_REQUEST['update']` and he can check to see if that variable exists.  A more appropriate method would be to verify the request method as POST and/or verify the variable(s) he wants to work with exist and have the values he expects.

Comment: Additionally, your code still suffers the same problem as his.  You have to transport the value between pages and make them persist.  Config.php only sets title IF it receives `$_REQUEST['websitetitle']` and sets it to that value.  When you include Config.php it will essentially contain nothing and so you are echoing a variable that doesn't exist when you try to `echo $title;`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    // config.php
    if(isset($_POST['update'])) {
        $title=strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['websitetitle']));
    }
?>

 <title><?php require_once('Config.php'); echo $title; ?> </title>

<fieldset>
    <legend style='width:500px;'><h3>Website Title</h3></legend>
    <label><h4> Change Website Title </h4></label>
    <form method='POST'>
    <input type='text' name='websitetitle' placeholder='Website Title'/> <br />
    <input type='submit' value='Update' class='btn btn-small btn-primary' name='update'>
    </form>
  </fieldset>
```

What you did is redirecting your user to the config.php after submitting the form.
what you want to do is to reload your actual page and then let the included script do what it should before the title tag is set.

Answer (score 0):

The answer above looks ok, but I would use php sessions. You could get rid of global.php and change config.php to

```
<?php 
    if (issest($_REQUEST['websitetitle'])) {
        $_SESSION['title'] = $_REQUEST['websitetitle'];
    }
?>
```

Then place `$_SESSION['title']` where you need a dynamic title. 
Also, be sure to add `session_start();` at the VERY top of the document.

Answer (score 0):

No where in any of your code did you save the value to be re-iterated later.  Every time your browser loads a new page it forgets everything that you didn't specifically tell it to keep.

You can write the information to a database, a file, a cookie or a session.

**For a session example:**

```
<?php

$title = ( isset($_SESSION) && isset($_SESSION['title']) ) ? $_SESSION['title'] : 'Original, unaltered page title here';

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
  </head>
```

Page that receives the form:

```
<?php

if ( isset($_REQUEST['websitetitle']) && !empty($_REQUEST['websitetitle']) )
{
  if ( !isset($_SESSION) ) session_start();
  $_SESSION['title'] = $_REQUEST['websitetitle'];
}
```

The reason for the `!isset($_SESSION)` condition to `session_start();` is that if you call `session_start()` when there is already an active session it throws an error.  If you are on a production system that is configured correctly then this error will be tucked away in a log file out of site, but it will still be there filling up your log files with pointless warnings.  It is possible to configure PHP to automatically generate sessions, making our calling `session_start()` pointless as well.

In my example, I don't start a session unless the person submits the form.  You don't need a session for every tom, dick, harry and bot that crawls across your page.  You only need sessions for the ones that click "Update".

Keep in mind that sessions are not the right answer if you want the site title to change permanently and/or for all users.  A session is an exclusive storage of information between the server and client.  If I change the site title to "Hello World!" then I will see "Hello World!" for the duration of my session, but you will not.